# how can add nasted slider in home page on magento?

Tags: magento

now i m using the magento1.9 and install theme is "http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-theme-electronics-online-by-pagayo.html" 
i add the nasted slider with image thumbnail in my home page.
nasted slider link is below "http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html"
plz suggestion me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a page in `your_theme_/template/page/html/nested-slider.phtml` with Nested Slider.

In the `your_theme_/template/page/html/header.phtml` call new page.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/nested-slider.phtml')->toHtml();?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('nested-slider'); ?> // displays the page where it is used
```

Once you are ready to pass the images to static blocks.
Use the code below to call the images within the framework of the slide where it is used the images

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('id_block_static')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this i suggest you to use the best nested tab slider extension developed for Magento by M-Connect Media and its available free for Magento community.
You can utilize this extension to create multiple tabs and add multiple banners sliders in each tab and in results you will get multiple tabs with multiple sliders in each.
It's available for both Magento 1 and 2

Magento 1 - https://www.mconnectmedia.com/nested-slider.html
Magento 2 - https://www.mconnectmedia.com/nested-slider-magento2.html